# test window.location.reload with jasmine typescript

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine

I got a problem with mocking the window.location.reload() functionality within Jasmine.

I have this function:

```
 public refresh(): void {
    if (this.selectedLanguage && this.selectedLanguage !== LanguageManager.selectedLanguage) {
      LanguageManager.changeSelectedLanguage(this.selectedLanguage);
      window.location.reload(true);
    }
  }
```

I tried creating the following test:

```
 it('should change language and reload page', () => {

    LanguageManager.selectedLanguage = LanguageManager.LANGUAGE_EN_EN;
    component.selectedLanguage = LanguageManager.LANGUAGE_RO_RO;
    spyOn(window.location, "reload").arguments(true).and.callFake(function () {
      console.log("fake reload");
    });
    component.refresh();
  });
```

I want to mock the location reload function but I get this error:

```
Error: <spyOn> : reload is not declared writable or has no setter
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

I tried also just: `spyOn(window.location, "reload");` but i got the same error.
Can someone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Since then did you find any solution?